# firebase data to comparison in render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I need help to compare the firebase data (if)and render the right component.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
export default class EstoqueScreen extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var id=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase.database().ref().child('users/'+id).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        var tipoUsuario=snapshot.val().tipo
    });
}
render(){
    console.log(this.tipoUsuario);
    if(this.tipoUsuario==='admin'){
        return(
            <View>
                 <EstoqueAdminScreen/>
            </View>
        )
    }else if(this.tipoUsuario==='vendedor'){
        return(
            <View>
                 <EstoqueVendScreen/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
  export default class EstoqueScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        state = {
          loading: true,
          tipoUsuario: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      var id=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      firebase.database().ref().child('users/'+id).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        this.setState({ tipoUsuario: snapshot.val().tipo, loading: false })        
      });
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state.tipoUsuario);
        if(this.state.loading){
          return (
            <View>Loading</View>
          )
        }
        if(this.state.tipoUsuario==='admin'){
            return(
                <View>
                    <EstoqueAdminScreen/>
                </View>
            )
        }else if(this.state.tipoUsuario==='vendedor'){
            return(
                <View>
                    <EstoqueVendScreen/>
                </View>
            )
        }
        return (
          <View>No hay tipo</View>
        )
    }
  }
```

Comment: TypeError: null is not an object(evaluating 'this.state.tipoUsuario')